# Why is FileStream.Seek behaving in two different ways?

Tags: c#, io, filestream, streamreader

Here is the code I'm using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var firstLine = sr.ReadLine();
    var indexNumber = (firstLine.Length + 2) * sizeof(Char);
    var byteNumber = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(firstLine + Environment.NewLine);

    var otherline = sr.ReadLine();
    var otherline2 = sr.ReadLine();
    var otherline3 = sr.ReadLine();

    comparisonCollection.Add(new int[] { indexNumber, byteNumber });

    fs.Seek(indexNumber, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var indexLine = sr.ReadLine();
    sr.DiscardBufferedData();
    fs.Seek(byteNumber, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var secondLine = sr.ReadLine();
    sr.DiscardBufferedData();
}
```

indexNumber and byteNumber evaluate to the same number (in this case 440).
The first Seek/Readline gives me the expected result of the second line in the file, but the second Seek/Readline (using the same arguments) gives me an empty string. I think I must be misunderstanding how something works. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Char/String are two byte in c# with a private property that indicates if each character is one or two bytes.  The Encoding methods can set and read this private property.  So method 1 is using 2 bytes for the size.  The 2nd method your are using both Ascii and Unicode (WHY).

Comment: using ascii and Unicode was an attempt to see if my original attempt to get the byte count (var indexNumber = (firstLine.Length + 2) * sizeof(Char);
) was the cause of my problem.

Comment: You really should get the byte count from the byte[] after the Encoding is performed.  The encoding/decoding will change the length because you can have a mixture of both one and two bytes characters in a string.

Comment: You have to discard buffered data *before* you read.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, as long as I make sure the encoding for the `StreamReader` matches the actual encoding of the data in the file, and use `Unicode` for that encoding. So, I suspect you have an encoding problem (and I mean, besides the ridiculous expression `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode`...that's equivalent to just `System.Text.Unicode`...the `ASCIIEncoding` in that context is useless). Unfortunately, you didn't bother to provide an actual [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so it's impossible to say exactly what the problem is or to provide an actual answer.